# Problema con array multidimensionales 3x3 funcion de borrar item

Tags: php, array

Buen día colegas, tengo un problema con arrays que me está rompiendo la cabeza, resulta que tengo este arreglo dimensional.

```
 array(3) { 
[1]=> array(1) {["PC150"]=> 
array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "HABPC" [1]=> string(2) "PC" [2]=> string(1) "2" 
[3]=> string(24) "EXTRACTOR PREMIUM CHOICE" [4]=> string(5) "Pieza" [5]=> 
string(1) "2" [6]=> string(13) " $ 154.00 USD" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["5PC-ACC01"]=> 
array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "HABPC" [1]=> string(2) "PC" [2]=> string(1) 
"3" [3]=> string(24) "EXTRACTOR PREMIUM CHOICE" [4]=> string(5) "Pieza" 
[5]=> 
string(1) "3" [6]=> string(12) " $ 39.00 USD" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["5PC-ACC05"]=> 
array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "HABPC" [1]=> string(2) "PC" [2]=> string(1) 
"3" [3]=> string(24) "EXTRACTOR PREMIUM CHOICE" [4]=> string(5) "Pieza" 
[5]=> string(1) "3" [6]=> string(11) " $ 7.00 USD" } } }
```

En un archivo json quedaría mas entendible de la siguiente manera.

```
{"1":{"PC150":
["HABPC","PC","2","EXTRACTOR PREMIUM CHOICE","Pieza","2"," $ 154.00 
USD"]},
"2":{"5PC-ACC01":
 ["HABPC","PC","3","EXTRACTOR PREMIUM 
CHOICE","Pieza","3"," $ 39.00 USD"]},
"3":{"5PC-ACC05":
["HABPC","PC","3","EXTRACTOR PREMIUM CHOICE","Pieza","3"," $ 7.00 USD"]}}
```

Lo que necesito es iterar el arreglo y borrar el index y volver a reordenar los index.

Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

La variable modelo es el identificador que le paso ejemplo [PC150] o [5PC-ACC01], para poder borrarlo.

```
eliminar($modelo){
  //lo obtengo de una cookie y lo guaro en arreglo

  $aCarrito = json_decode($_COOKIE['carrito'], true);
  $c  = $_COOKIE['contItems']; //tambien obtengo mi contador de articulos
 //itero la primer vez
foreach ($aCarrito as $key => $ubc) {
//en $key se guardan 1,2,3,4 $ubc es otro array
    //itero ubx para obtener el modelo
     foreach ($ubc as $mode => $mod) {
        //hago coincidir los modelos con el modelo pasado en la funcion
        if ($mode == $modelo) {
             // elimino la posicion del arreglo
            unset($aCarrito[$i][$modelo]);


        }

    }
    $i++;
}
  }
```

Y queda el arreglo de la siguiente manera cuando se elimina(eso si funciona, borrar el contenido en ese index).

*`{"1":[ ],"2":[ ],"3":[ ]}`* , pero yo quiero que se borre completo con el index también probé con  *`unset($aCarrito[ $i ]);`*, y también elimina el index completo(como deseo), pero necesito que se vuelva a reordenar el array.

¿Alguna idea para borrar el array pasándole la variable $modelo y reordenar todo?

Comment: Que quieres decir con (eso si funciona), y "a veces de jalon borra todos".  Si el comportamiento es impredecible, entonces tambien va a ser dificil ayudarte

Comment: Una recomendación cuando haces `unset()` de un elemento de `array` mientras lo estás recorriendo: almacena en un nuevo `array` el que quieres editar, y recorres este nuevo array, y de acuerdo a sus índices, vas haciendo `unset()` sobre los elementos del array original. Así no pierdes integridad mientras realizas el bucle.

Comment: @quinqui muchas gracias por el consejo, lo tendré mucho en cuenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una función para ti..

```
/* Array de Ejemplo */ 
$array = array(array('PC150'=>['HABPC', 'PC']),
               array('5PC-ACC01'=>['HABPC', 'PC']),
               array('5PC-ACC05'=>['HABPC', 'PC']),
               array('5PC-ACC06'=>['HABPC', 'PC']));

function deleteIdx( array $arr, string $whatever ) {
    $idk = array_map(function($e) use ($whatever){
        return key($e) == $whatever ? false : $e;
    }, $arr);
    return array_values(array_filter($idk));
}

$newArr = deleteIdx($array, 'PC150');
```

Esta función se puede utilizar en otros arreglos similares, y permite especificar el indice a borrar en el segundo parámetro. Lo único que debes hacer es almacenar el array filtrado en una variable.

Comment: Wow, no pensé que en tan poquito codigo se pudiera hacer eso